# How to remove all elements inside <style> tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, styles

So as per my title question, how to remove all elements inside style tag.

I have style tag inside the body. I am just retrieving the HTML code.

```
<body>
 <style>
    td {...};
    a {....};
 </style>
<body>
```

I have remove the style tag alone. But not the elements inside it.
I can still retrieve the:

```
<body>
    td {...};
    a {....};
<body>
```

I also need to remove the

```
td {...};
a {....};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can query and remove style tags with the DOM tools. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?  The question is not clear, and it looks like you're trying to remove an html element.  Why put it in in the first place?

Comment: What's a `style5` tag?

Comment: @MattBryant, yes I am trying to remove a tag including what's inside it.

Comment: @elclanrs It seems like the link is broken.

Comment: @user2510841 the link is fine.

Comment: It seems you are trying to process HTML text, which isn't a good idea unless you have an HTML parser handy. You may be best to create an element, insert the HTML as the element's innerHTML, remove the style elements using DOM mehtods, then retrieve the innerHTML. Note that this may result in different HTML in different browsers, but it should be effectively the same (i.e. it should produce an almost indistinguishable DOM, but not necessarily identical).

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to remove all css elements in the body, you could do something like:

```
var x = document.body.getElementsByTagName("style");
for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    x[i].parentElement.removeChild(x[i]);
```

If you are trying to remove just the first one in the body:

```
var x = document.body.getElementsByTagName("style");
if (x.length)
    x[0].parentElement.removeChild(x[0]);
```

Edit: Removed method using `map`.  Crazy Train correctly pointed out that it probably wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid your `.map()` solution won't be quite that simple. Because you're removing the elements from the DOM, they're also being removed from the `HTMLCollection`, which means that there will be indices that are skipped.

Comment: I considered that for the `for` loop, but wasn't sure what `map` compiles down to.  The loop is definitely the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove an HTML element. You can do it like this, assuming that the  tag is the only one in the document

```
(var styleElt=document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0]).parentNode.removeChild(styleElt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project is using jQuery you can easily remove the content of the style tag with a really short bit of script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('style').html("");
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QKVrD/1/) showing that it works.